# Loading css & javascript libraries in webview with Phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery, xcode, mobile, cordova

I'm developing a mobile app using Phonegap and it is primarily using the webView for content. One of the pages in the webView uses SwipeJS but when I load all of the dependent files(css & js) the images do not display. I've been trouble shooting this issue for the last few hours and I think the best solution is to load all of the assets on the webview rather than in the app.

The problem is when I add all of the assets to the page webview and then load the page thru the app none of the styles or script load. If I go to the page that i'm loading in the webView in a web browser that assets are all there and the SwipeJS gallery works. So i'm a little confused, why isn't the webview rendering the page with the working gallery??

Here is the header source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <title>Title</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/min.css" />

    <script src="js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.dotdotdot-1.3.0.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova-2.0.0.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/swipe.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
           $(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
               $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
               $.mobile.ajaxLinksEnabled = false;
               $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
               $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
           });

           $(document).ready(function(){

               // for select dropdown nav
               $("#main-nav").change(function(){
                   if ($(this).val()!='') {
                       var mobPage ="http://m.example.com/"+$(this).val()+"?mode=Native";
                       $('#content').load(mobPage);
                   }
               });

               $('a').live("click", function(){
                   event.preventDefault();
                   var artPage = $(this).attr('href');
                   var mobPage = artPage+"?mode=Native";
                   $("#content").load(mobPage);
               });

               $('.ui-navbar a').live("click", function(){
                   event.preventDefault();
                   var artPage = $(this).attr('href');
                   var mobPage = "http://m.example.com/"+artPage+"?mode=Native";
                   $("#content").load(mobPage);
               });

               var mobPage = "http://m.example.com/?mode=Native";

               $('#content').load(mobPage, function() {
                   $('#content').fadeIn(500);
               });
         });


                        </script>

        </head>
```

Comment: Can you add in the html code from your <head> for your js & css files? They are all contained within the /www/ folder right?

Comment: Yes, all of the assets are in the /www/ directory. I've added the source from the head.